# Getting empty query PHP error when form is submitted via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

When my form is submitted (via Ajax), I'm getting the following error message:

```
[17-Oct-2012 11:46:29] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() [<a href='function.mysqli-query'>function.mysqli-query</a>]: Empty query in /home1/xenongro/public_html/testing/enrolment/thanks.php on line 32
```

I have a suspicion that it's something to do with the if/else statements, but not sure what the actual problem is.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php

$firstname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname']));
$lastname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname']));
$worktel = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['worktel']));

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxxx', '<xxxx>', 'xxxx')
or die ('Could not connect to MySQL server.');

if ($level != "IOSH Managing Safely"){
 if ($funding == "Self Funding"){
  $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
"VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
}
else if ($funding == "Employer Funding"){
$query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
"VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
}
}
else if ($level == "IOSH Managing Safely"){
if ($funding == "Self Funding"){
$query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
"VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
}

else if ($funding == "Employer Funding"){
$query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
"VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
    }
    }

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die ('error querying database');
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Comment: means ur program is not entering any of the condition blocks!!

Comment: So where are $level and $funding defined?

Comment: Is `$_POST` set? Does your AJAX request actually use the `POST` method? Where do $funding and $level come from(?), they are nowhere defined in your sample code (please always bother to show all relevant snippets). And why don't you use proper database escaping?

Comment: print out your `$level` and `$funding` values and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var_dump($query);
var_dump($funding);
```

just before

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

it'll give you more information

I suspect that `$funding` might have slight variation to your constant strings

might be typo / extra space / cap case

Answer (score 0):

There are two situation where no query is being set:
the level does not match the string, or the funding does not match the string.
It might be a problem with the spaces.

Worse, you don't use mysql_real_escape_string and unless magic_quotes_gpc is on, this allows an attacker to inject his SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`$funding` doesn't appear to be defined in the code example provided, so none of your `if`'s will match.